# How to use codeigniter flash variable?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, codeigniter

m struggling with Flash Data in CodeIgniter.

I basically want to:

add a question to a database redirect user back to a page show a success pop-up message "Your question has been created"

So far I can add the category successfully to the db and the user input is validated correctly, only thing is I don't know how to create the pop up success message. (I don't want to load a success view), just redirect back to where they came from and show small message in the top corner or something.

Is flash data the right way to go?

Controller:-

```
 $create_data =  $this->input->post();
    if(isset($create_data['question'])){
    $this->load->model('Test_model', 'test');
    $insert_status = $this->test->insertQuestions($create_data['question']);
    if($insert_status){
            echo "Record Inserted";
        }
        else{
            echo "Insertion Failed";
        }
    }
$this->layout->view('test/create');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash data sounds like the way to go. You could do something like this:

```
if($insert_status){
    $notification = "Record Inserted";  
} else {
    $notification = "Insertion Failed";
}

$this->session->set_flashdata('notification', $notification);
redirect('controller/method','refresh');
```

Then access it with

`$this->session->flashdata('notification');`

The [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) is an invaluable source for this kind of information.

Comment: I would also code in some kind of parameter so you know "what color" to show error/success message in ;)

Comment: Yeah, ideally you would make a notification helper and pass that kind of information along as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
function insert(){
    $create_data =  $this->input->post();
    if(isset($create_data['question'])){
        $this->load->model('Test_model', 'test');
        $insert_status = $this->test->insertQuestions($create_data['question']);
        if($insert_status){
            //echo "Record Inserted";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Record Inserted'); //set session flash
            redirect('controller_name/insert', 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            //echo "Insertion Failed";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Insertion Failed'); //set session flash
            redirect('controller_name/insert', 'refresh');
        }
    }else{
        $this->layout->view('test/create');    
    }
}
?>
```

In View Page:

```
<p><?=$this->session->flashdata('msg')?></p>
```