# Getting flashdata in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect

I am saving an array in codeigniter flashdata as

```
//Show success message
$data = array(
 'message' => 'My message',
 'message2' => 'New Message'
);
$this->session->set_flashdata($data);
```

also tried as

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('myData', $data);
```

after redirecting the page I am trying to retrieve as

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Which is not  working for me even

```
print_r($this->session->flashdata('myData'));
```

is not working

How to get flashdata set as an array?

Comment: Complete code please. Especially the part where you try to read the session.

Answer (score 0):

save that flashdata in array, like:

```
$data = array(
 'message' => 'My message',
 'message2' => 'New Message'
);
$this->session->set_flashdata("someone",$data);
redirect("home","refresh");

And in view:

print_r($this->session->flashdata('someone'));
```

Comment: echo is better for view i think than print r `<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('notification'); ?>`

Comment: @mustang83 yeah but how to echo array variable it's just for reference

Answer (score 0):

Example: From another post.

**Sample 1**

```
if($insert_status){
    $notification = "Record Inserted";  
} else {
    $notification = "Insertion Failed";
}

$this->session->set_flashdata('notification', $notification);
redirect('controller/method','refresh');
```

**Sample 2**

```
$notification  = array(
 'message' => 'test',
 'message_one' => 'text'
);

$this->session->set_flashdata('notification', $notification);
redirect('controller/method','refresh');
```

[How to use codeigniter flash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692883/how-to-use-codeigniter-flash-variable)

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

You must place the echoed code to the view of the controller you redirected to.

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('notification');?>
```

Bootstrap

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('notification')) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('notification'); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, when you use `$this->session->set_flashdata('myData', $data);` try this one

```
$myData = $this->session->flashdata('myData');
echo "Message: ".$myData['message'].PHP_EOL;
echo "Message2: ".$myData['message2'];
```

Will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At controller

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');

redirect(base_url(),$data);
```

At view Page

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message_name'); ?>
```